# Why are two functions running on button click instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 buttons in a page. One of the buttons saves a date that is input via 3 textboxes.
The other one calls a function that does some data manipulation.

This is what I have from the first button referred above.

```
<input type="submit" name="gravarnext" value="Gravar" />

<?php
if (isset($_POST['gravarnext'])) { 
    if ($_POST['atextfield1'] <= 0 OR $_POST['atextfield2'] <= 0 OR $_POST['atextfield3'] <= 0 OR $_POST['atextfield1'] > 31 OR $_POST['atextfield2'] > 12 OR $_POST['atextfield3'] < 2013){ ?>
        <script>window.alert("Um ou mais valores são inválidos (Dia 1-31 / Mês 1-12 / Ano 2013+).");</script>
    <?php } else {
                $qp = "UPDATE login.next SET dia = '".$_POST['atextfield1']."'";
                $rqp = mysql_query($qp);
                $qp = "UPDATE login.next SET mes = '".$_POST['atextfield2']."'";
                $rqp = mysql_query($qp);
                $qp = "UPDATE login.next SET ano = '".$_POST['atextfield3']."'";
                $rqp = mysql_query($qp);
                echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
                <script>window.alert("Data do próximo sorteio atualizada com sucesso!");</script>
    <?php } 
}
```

And this is the respective code from the second button

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Finalizar</button>

<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var r=confirm("Depois de carregar 'ok', todas as ações tomadas são irreversíveis. Desejas continuar?");
        if (r==true)
        {
            <?php
            //Refresha o palpite do utilizador para 0 e guarda o palpite antigo como ultpalpite
            $qp5 = "UPDATE login.users SET ultpalpite = palpiteatual";
            $rqp5 = mysql_query($qp5);
            //Gera o número sorteado
            $numsort = rand(1,50);
            $qp2 = "UPDATE login.sorteio SET ultsorteio = '".$numsort."'";
            $rqp2 = mysql_query($qp2);
            $qp3 = "UPDATE login.next SET numsorteado = '".$numsort."'";
            $rqp3 = mysql_query($qp3); 
            //Adiciona +1 ao vezesganhou do(s) vencedor(es)
            $qp4 = "UPDATE login.users SET vezesganhou = vezesganhou + 1 WHERE ultpalpite = '".$numsort."'";
            $rqp4 = mysql_query($qp4);
            //Atualiza data do ultimo sorteio
            $d = date('j');
            $m = date('n');
            $y = date('Y');
            $aqp1 = "UPDATE login.sorteio SET diaultsort = '".$d."', mesultsort = '".$m."', anoultsort = '".$y."'";
            $arqp1 = mysql_query($aqp1);
            ?>
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
</script>
```

So, my problem is that whenever I click the first button (called "Gravar"), everything run perfectly except that the function associated to the second button (called "Finalizar") runs too. What may be causing this?
And don't worrie with the sql vulnerabilities and/or bad coding. This is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Your problem is of different nature, but this just asks for a [malicious SQL to be injected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and ruin all your data... Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390836/1667004) regarding security...

For your problem here: PHP is executed on the SERVER side, BEFORE the content is being sent to the user. JavaScript is not evaluated until it reaches the client side (browser). So your `if` condition doesn't do anything, the PHP contents of `myFunction()` are executed no matter what...

Comment: I think you are mixing javaScript and PHP the worng way. The PHP code for the second button will always be executed by the server before even sending the DATA to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button Finalizar always runs for a very simple reason:

You can't combine PHP code with a JavaScript function. PHP code is run before it is sent to the client (hence it's called a server-side language).

If you had the following script:

```
function myJavascriptFunction() {
     <?php echo 'This is some PHP'; ?>
}
```

The client would interpret it as:

```
function myJavascriptFunction() {
    This is some PHP
}
```

which will give you errors. Again, PHP is run server-side.

In order to run PHP from JavaScript, you need something called AJAX. Basically you save whatever you want to do in a separate PHP file. You can run that PHP file silently whenever you like to.

Have a go at this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: Why w3schools again? (read [this](http://w3fools.com/) why I ask...)And "running a PHP code from Javascript" is also a deceiving statement: you issue requests that trigger the execution of PHP code...

Comment: W3schools is easy for beginners because it has some background information and snippets that allows them to copy paste. I am very well aware that w3schools is a bad resource with many invalid information. I'm also very well aware that you don't actually run PHP code from Javascript, but trigger a new HTTP request instead. We are dealing with a beginner. Understanding the background of whatever you do comes over time.

Comment: @FábioMartinho If an answer is correct, you can press the big V left of the answer. This allows people with similar issues in the future to find this answer easily. It also makes people answer your future questions faster and better ;)

Comment: Yes, I know. I had to wait 1 minute in order to click it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed js and php in wrong way ... PhP will always run ahead of javascript so the php code within myfunction will always run irrespective of the condition .
the possible solution to your problem can be to all the other page using ajax on the confirm condition being true It can be like

```
 function myFunction()
{
    var r=confirm("Depois de carregar 'ok', todas as ações tomadas são irreversíveis. Desejas continuar?");
    if (r==true)
    {
        $.ajax{
                 url   : 'yourpage.php',
                 data  : {"data you want in page"}
              }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and on yourpage.php write your this one php code

```
<?php
    //Refresha o palpite do utilizador para 0 e guarda o palpite antigo como ultpalpite
    $qp5 = "UPDATE login.users SET ultpalpite = palpiteatual";
    $rqp5 = mysql_query($qp5);
    //Gera o número sorteado
    $numsort = rand(1,50);
    $qp2 = "UPDATE login.sorteio SET ultsorteio = '".$numsort."'";
    $rqp2 = mysql_query($qp2);
    $qp3 = "UPDATE login.next SET numsorteado = '".$numsort."'";
    $rqp3 = mysql_query($qp3); 
    //Adiciona +1 ao vezesganhou do(s) vencedor(es)
    $qp4 = "UPDATE login.users SET vezesganhou = vezesganhou + 1 WHERE ultpalpite = '".$numsort."'";
    $rqp4 = mysql_query($qp4);
    //Atualiza data do ultimo sorteio
    $d = date('j');
    $m = date('n');
    $y = date('Y');
    $aqp1 = "UPDATE login.sorteio SET diaultsort = '".$d."', mesultsort = '".$m."', anoultsort = '".$y."'";
    $arqp1 = mysql_query($aqp1);
    ?>
```

Give it a try....

Comment: Actually made a way around it using POST. It's working great now. Anyway thanks :)